# React native responsive side menu

Tags: react-native, responsive, side-menu

I am using the library react-navigation-drawer for my app side menu.

My app should be working on iphone and iPad as well.

The default side menu of this library is working well on iPhone.
But on iPad, side menu should be always visible on my app.

I could implement this by `drawerLockMode:'locked-open'` on some pages.
But Side menu has been overlayed on content screen. and could not doing any actions on content screen.
Even content screen has been pushed aside as width of side menu.

Anyone help me how to implement the responsive side menu on iPhone and iPad?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a code example? A printScreen of what you already made or of what you want? Add it to the question to make her a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever app is running on iPad, set `drawerType={'permanent'}` for Drawer.Navigator
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawertype

Comment: Nice solution. I didn't know there is 'permanent' case on drawerType.
Seems it had been added on react-navigation v5.
I've update it to V5 and working well now.

Thanks Very Well